# WordPress Query and display two custom post types in one loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created two custom posts types and each has several categories. I need to run one query, return results for both post types, ("problems","solutions") in different sections of my markup. I cannot change my markup without rewriting tons of jquery which is dependent on the IDs of each "tip". I've tried various loops with no success. Can someone give me some insight? WordPress loop below:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('problems', 'solutions'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('my-category')
        )
    )
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $tipID = array('tip-1','tip2','tip-3','tip-4','tip-5');
$tipID_count = count($tipID);
$tipID_index = 0;
while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
?>

<div class="tooltip" <?php $k = $tipID_index % $tipID_count; echo "id=#$tipID[$k]"; $tipID_index++; ?>>
    <dl>
        <dt><a href="" class="imageText">1</a></dt>
<!--///////problems\\\\\\\-->
            <dd class="problem">
                <span class="close pull_right"><a href="" class="imageText">close</a></span>
                    ...do stuff
                <div class="tip-foot"></div>
            </dd>
<!--///////solutions\\\\\\\-->
            <dd class="solution">
                <span class="close pull_right"><a href="" class="imageText">close</a></span>
                    ...do stuff
                <div class="tip-foot"></div>
            </dd>

        </dl>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two arrays, a $problems_arr and a $solutions_arr, and put the problem post ids in the problems array and the solutions post ids in the solutions array.

This code is untested, but this is an example:

```
$problems_arr = array();
$solutions_arr = array();
while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
    if(get_post_type() == 'problems')
       array_push($problems_arr, get_the_ID());
    else
       array_push($solutions_arr, get_the_ID());
endwhile;
for(i = 0; i<count($problems_arr); i++){
?>
   <div class="tooltip" <?php $k = $tipID_index % $tipID_count; echo "id=#$tipID[$k]"; $tipID_index++; ?>>
```

You can display the content of the post by using the post ids, eg:

echo apply_filters ('the_content', get_post_field ('post_content', $problems_arr[i]))

You don't want to save the post content in an array because it would take up a lot of memory, so just store the post ids.

Comment: I guess I should clarify. I IDs i'm referring to don't have anything to do with the "post ID". Just div IDs. I just need to display the content of both custom posts in one loop...

Comment: You can use the post ids to display the content by doing